# tawk.io plugin not work on first time page load

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails

I am using tawk.to plugin by adding js in application.js but at first page load it is not working what will be solution in js or rails?

Comment: Whenever you are asking other people for help, who are not right next to you, you have to put a lot more effort in recreating in their minds, the scenario you are currently experiencing. "It is not working" is never a good way to do that.

I have some experience with tawk.to, but have no idea what to make of "it is not working."

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to the panel of your Tawk.to account, then to the Manage button, select the property to manage.
Then in Configuration of the graphic component, uncheck the option "Hide estimated waiting time".
Save, and the problem is solved.
This solution worked for me.